# How to redefiine maxAliasesForCollections in LoaderOptions?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, yaml

i am using `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to bind my yaml file, which is defined in `spring.profile.active`, to the class.
The problem is that this file is using a lot of aliases in it. By default `LoaderOptions()` class has maxAliasesForCollections defined as 50.

Due to it next exception is throw ->

`org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Number of aliases for non-scalar nodes exceeds the specified max=50`

Tried using

```
class UnlimitedYamlPropertiesFactoryBean : YamlPropertiesFactoryBean() {
    @Override
    override fun createYaml(): Yaml {
        val loaderOptions = LoaderOptions()
        loaderOptions.isAllowDuplicateKeys = false
        loaderOptions.maxAliasesForCollections = Int.MAX_VALUE
        loaderOptions.allowRecursiveKeys = true
        return Yaml(loaderOptions)
    }
}

class YamlPropertySourceFactory : PropertySourceFactory {
    override fun createPropertySource(name: String?, encodedResource: EncodedResource): PropertySource<*> {
        val factory: YamlPropertiesFactoryBean = UnlimitedYamlPropertiesFactoryBean()
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.resource)
        val properties: Properties? = factory.getObject()
        return PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.resource.filename!!, properties!!)
    }
}

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = ["classpath:foo.yml"], factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory::class)
class YamlFooProperties {
    val mtProxy: List<FooConfigs>? = null
}
```

If i don't have this YML file defined in `spring.profile.active`, it works perfectly ok

i tried debugging and it does not even call `UnlimitedYamlPropertiesFactoryBean` and throws exception before that

Is There any workaround for this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.